# Correct Record Entries On Insert (SQL Trigger)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a lookup table named GLOBAL_TRACKING that needs to be in sync with data in another table, USER. Due to some issues with the code in a particular instance of user account creation on the front end (I know - ideally, this should be fixed in the code, but I don't have that option), I am getting entries in the GLOBAL_TRACKING table that have a NULL value set for a field that should never be NULL. Since this only happens on initial account creation, I can assume that the LOGIN_ID field of the USER record should always match the ALT_ID field of the GLOBAL_TRACKING table.

I want to do a check for these cases, and if it's null, pull the LOGIN_ID value from the USER table and insert it into the ALT_ID field of the GLOBAL_TRACKING table before inserting. I've tried doing a regular insert trigger (updating it on insert), but wasn't successful. I'm currently trying an 'INSTEAD OF INSERT' trigger, and running into similar errors (It's being trapped at the application-level, with the exception: "Invalid object name 'UPDATED'."). Is something like this possible? Here is my instead of trigger:

```
    DECLARE @GlobalID     as NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @AlternateID  as NVARCHAR(255)

    SET @GlobalID = (SELECT GLOBAL_ID FROM inserted)

    SET @AlternateID = (SELECT ALT_ID FROM inserted)

    IF (@AlternateID IS NULL
        AND ((SELECT COUNT(LOGIN_ID)
              FROM USER
              WHERE USER_ID = @GlobalID) > 0))
    BEGIN
        SET @AlternateID = (SELECT LOGIN_ID
                            FROM USER
                            WHERE USER_ID = @GlobalID)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE GLOBAL_TRACKING
            SET ALT_ID = @AlternateID 
            WHERE GLOBAL_ID = @GlobalID
        END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

something along this

```
DECLARE @GlobalID     as NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @AlternateID  as NVARCHAR(255)

    SET @GlobalID = (SELECT GLOBAL_ID FROM inserted)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)

SET @SQL='SELECT ALT_ID FROM inserted where GLOBAL_ID= ''' + @GlobalID+'''' ;

EXEC (@SQL)


    SET @AlternateID = EXEC (@SQL)

    IF (@AlternateID IS NULL
        AND ((SELECT COUNT(LOGIN_ID)
              FROM USER
              WHERE USER_ID = @GlobalID) > 0))
    BEGIN
        SET @AlternateID = (SELECT LOGIN_ID
                            FROM USER
                            WHERE USER_ID = @GlobalID)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE GLOBAL_TRACKING
            SET ALT_ID = @AlternateID 
            WHERE GLOBAL_ID = @GlobalID
        END
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm running into a syntax error at 'Set @AlternateID = EXEC (@SQL)' on the 'EXEC' keyword. Also, a few questions - whats the purpose of the first, initial 'EXEC (@SQL)' call? And what is the difference between the way we are grabbing the GlobalID and the way EXEC would do it? Thanks again!